# Navigation bar button doesn't show in navigationbar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I set `rightBarButton` on `navigationBar` programmatically, but that doesn't show, though the title is showing alright.

Here is my code form `AppDelegate`:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor        = APP_COLOR
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor           = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:Constants.APP_REGULAR_FONT_WITH_SIZE(size: 18), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```

And here is code from my `viewController` where I am trying to add `rightBarButton`.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "logout"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(logoutButtonTapped))
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
}
```

I have also tried removing appearance settings still the button is not visible.

[image]

Comment: Where are you setting the title (Naeem) of this screen?

Comment: try to print self.navigationController see if its nil

Comment: @Adeel in viewWillAppear, i am get dataFrom database and then set name as navigationTitle

Comment: @AgentChocks. no its not nil brother

Comment: @Adeel when i come on this controller from rootViewController then its not showing, but when come here from other controller not rootViewController then it shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "test"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(logoutButtonTapped))

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

now this is works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `self.navigationController?.` in your code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(logoutButtonTapped))
}
```

Comment: still not showing, when i come on this controller from root viewController then this not showing, when come from other controller then this shows.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **self.navigationController?.navi...** instead of that use **self.navigationItem.rightBarButton...**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "logout"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(logoutButtonTapped))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
}
```

Hope your problem will be solved by this code. Thankyou.

Comment: still not showing, when i come on this controller from root viewController then this not showing, when come from other controller then this shows.

Comment: how did you come to this controller? `window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())` did you use this code or not? let me see your code of calling this controller, so that I can know how you get to this controller.

Comment: if you haven't use this `window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())` then you won't see navigationBar in your view. And if you come from certain controller then you should use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController(), animated: true)`. If you haven't this code then you won't get navigationBar.

Comment: let chatHistoryVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatHistoryVC") as! ChatHistoryVC
                            self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([chatHistoryVC], animated: true)

Comment: `let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
 let programSchedule = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SessionFeedbackController") as! SessionFeedbackController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(programSchedule, animated: false)` try this code I think it should work for you.